# unshift & splice don't work for observable arrays when calling from prototypes

Tags: javascript, mobx

Consider the following example with MobX 5.15.4:

```js
class Store {
  @observable.shallow items = [];
}

const store = new Store();
store.items = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
Array.prototype.push.apply(store.items, [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]);
Array.prototype.unshift.apply(store.items, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Calling `Array.prototype.unshift` for observable array doesn't work for me (while `Array.prototype.push` works). Here is a stack trace:

```
mobx.module.js:3390 Uncaught Error: [mobx.array] Index out of bounds, 14 is larger than 10
    at Array.set (mobx.module.js:3390)
    at Object.set (mobx.module.js:3058)
    at Proxy.unshift (<anonymous>)
    at Module../index.js (index.js:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:89)
    at Object.0 (index.js:6200)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:89)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at index.js:1
```

`Array.prototype.splice` also doesn't work:

```js
Array.prototype.splice.apply(store.items, [0, 0].concat([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Is it a bug or do I misunderstand something? I guess that I should use an observable array's prototype to make it working. I tried the following but still no luck:

```js
const observableArrayPrototype = store.items.__proto__;
observableArrayPrototype.unshift.apply(store.items, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use the spread operator? You can surely call

```
store.items.push([10, 11, 12, 13, 14]);
```

and be done. In case you have a `newItems` array, use

```
store.items.push(...newItems);
```

Otherwise, you need a loop.

Comment: [Another solution](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/2370#issuecomment-640785429) is to use `array.spliceWithArray(0, 0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])` that is independent on js function arguments' limit.

Answer (score 0):

for [getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) works

```js
let items = mobx.observable([]);

items = items.concat([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
console.log(items);

items.push.apply(items, [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]);
console.log(items);

items.unshift.apply(items, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(items);


let items1 = mobx.observable([]);
const observablePrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(items1);

items1 = items1.concat([5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
console.log(items1);

observablePrototype.push.apply(items1, [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]);
console.log(items1);

observablePrototype.unshift.apply(items1, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]);
console.log(items1);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobx/5.15.4/mobx.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly, it still doesn't work for me in my current project. Need to dig into it deeper in order to understand what's going wrong.